# Как поставить обработчик на потерю фокуса

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем есть поле. При получении фокуса(после клика) он меняет удаляет value. Как мне сделать, что-бы когда пользователь кликнул на что-то другое то value опять вернется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="abc" onblur="document.getElementById('abc').value = oldvalue">
```